# does 'getPath() method' replace 'Input/OutputStream in java?

Tags: java, buffer

i wrote the code
BUT I GOT THIS ERROR MESSAGE

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at chap01/sec03.exam04.NonBufferVsBufferExample.main(NonBufferVsBufferExample.java:7)"
```

And this is the code i wrote.

```
package sec03.exam04;
import java.io.*;
public class NonBufferVsBufferExample{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception  {
           String originalFilePath1 =    
                   NonBufferVsBufferExample.class.getResource("originalFile1.jpg").getPath();
           String targetFilePath1 = "C:/Temp/targetFile1.jpg";
           FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(originalFilePath1);
           FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(targetFilePath1);
           
           
           String originalFilePath2 = 
                   NonBufferVsBufferExample.class.getResource("originalFile2.jpg").getPath();
           String targetFilePath2 = "C:/Temp/targetFile2.jpg";
           FileInputStream fis2 = new FileInputStream(originalFilePath2);
           FileOutputStream fos2 = new FileOutputStream(targetFilePath2);
           BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis2);
           BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos2);
           
           long nonBufferedTime = copy(fis,fos);
           System.out.println("not using buffer: \t" + nonBufferedTime +"n/s");
           
           long bufferTime = copy(bis,bos);
           System.out.println("using buffer: \t\t" + bufferTime +"n/s" );
           
           fis.close();
           fos.close();
           bis.close();
           bos.close();
           }
    
           static int data = -1;
           public static long copy(InputStream is, OutputStream os) throws Exception {
               long start = System.nanoTime();
               while(true) {
                   data = is.read();
                   if(data == -1) break;
                   os.write(data);                 
               }
               os.flush();
               long end = System.nanoTime();
               return(end-start);
              
             }

}
```

when i replace some part about 'getPath()'  , that code works well

this is the part i replaced

```
   String targetFilePath1 = "C:/Temp/targetFile1.jpg";
           InputStream is = new FileInputStream("C:/Temp/originalFile1.jpg");
           OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(targetFilePath1);
           
               
          
           String targetFilePath2 = "C:/Temp/targetFile2.jpg";
           InputStream is2 = new FileInputStream("C:/Temp/originalFile2.jpg");
           OutputStream os2= new FileOutputStream(targetFilePath2);    
           BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is2);
           BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(os2);
```

================================================================================
i just replace using 'getPath()' into using 'InputStream'
but it works.
i don't know why first code doesn't work.
even that first code is that i just copy from book.

what makes that difference??

i'm wondering difference between 'using getPath()" and 'using InputStream'.

Comment: It seems that `NonBufferVsBufferExample.class.getResource("originalFile1.jpg")` is returning `null`.

Comment: Can you explain why that happens? I certainly saw the file is existing.